# CSS - Change background color of list on button hover

Tags: css, hover, css-animations, squarespace

In simplest terms: I have a list with a button inside of that list. I would like for my ****list** background color** to change upon **hovering over the button**. Please don't be mistaken for me wanting the button's background color to change.

Here's an example of what I want the list to do:

[image]
[image]

Unfortunately, because it's Squarespace. I have limited access to changing the current CSS. Instead what I can do is overwrite CSS with custom CSS which I've done in the past.

They have preset class's for each element. The following are the class names:

```
.user-items-list
.list-item-content__button
```

I've been able to change the button color background on hover, you can reference this code here:

```
.user-items-list li:nth-child(1) .list-item-content__button:hover{
background-color:#2547A0!important;
opacity: 1;
transition: 0.2s;
}

.user-items-list li:nth-child(1) .list-item-content__button{
 transition: 0.2s;
}
```

I would like to do this on multiple list's so the code can not be generalized (cannot make all other list's change the same color if I want them to be different colors) so please specify with "nth-child" or any other means.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the :has pseudo class. So you can do something like this:

```
.user-items-list li:nth-child(1):has(.list-item-content__button:hover){
    background-color:#2547A0!important;
    opacity: 1;
}

.user-items-list li:nth-child(1):has(.list-item-content__button){
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/OoShiit/1zdyrkne/9/

Look at the mdn web docs about the :has pseudo class:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has